# USB data transfer speed for external hdd

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I use an Asus Strix-GL504GM portable PC, to which I have connected external hdds via usb, for file transfer, but, even if initially the speed is acceptable, then it inexorably drops to ridiculous values. The HDDs are new, one formatted NFTS but the other EXT4. I also set the parameters in the sysctl file like this:
vm.dirty_bytes = 50331648
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 16777216
But I didn't get appreciable results.
I am attaching images of the speed variation, which even with large files takes on extremely low values.
I would like to know if this is due to the PC or the software. Thanks for any comments on this.
[speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJF1I.png)

[speed_01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkT5T.png)

Comment: Are the HDDs separately powered? Your PC may not have enough to share,. Under powering could lead to USB timeouts, retries, and other throughput wasters.